# How to put the icon and the text in the same line

Tags: html, css, button, text, icons

The globe icon and the word language is putted in the same line and I try to enlarge the button but it still can't solve my problem.

For my project I want to put an I icon on the button, in the language button, I want to put a globe Icon on the left hand side of the text language, I found the Icon on css.gg

https://css.gg/globe-alt

[image]

The button now look like this, the icon is on the top of the text I thought that the width of the button is not enough, so i tried to enlarge the button but it still on the top of the text, I think it is not the problem of size, I tried to change `inline-block` to `block` but it don't work either

Html

```html
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn" style="font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;"><i class="gg-globe-alt"></i>Language</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="https://example.com/en/" target="_blank">English</a>
          <a href="https://example.com/zh-rg/" target="_blank">正體中文</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Css

```css
/*dropdown button*/
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #292827;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #292827;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #3b3a39
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #292827;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to style the i element instead. For example:

```
.dropbtn > i {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, It worked to me, but one more question, I use the icons from different website, like css.gg, fluent ui, and font awesome, and it become like this [image](https://imgur.com/a/sH25ixp), the instragram icon become bigger as it it from css.gg, and other is from fluent design, how to make them into the same size

Comment: @CtrlCCtrlV perhaps, you need to target the Instagram icon via CSS class and change the size of both height and width properties to your desired values instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex` in your `.dropbtn` class for this.

```
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #292827;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put
`display: flex;`
for .dropbtn and it will work.

Comment: Maybe some more detail as to why it would work?

Comment: flexbox has many features.for more detail visit :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Try display: flex; in .dropbtn instead of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample

```
<span class="b">Aliquam</span> 
<span class="b">venenatis</span>
```

CSS

```
span.b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;    
  background-color: yellow; 
}
```